# Laravel 9 route groups with two conditions

Tags: laravel, routes

In my users table I have a field (boolean):

active

My routes currently use

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function ()
```

but I want to do is to add the active so they will have to be authorised and active.

I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another middleware to group.

```
Route::middleware(['auth','active'])->group(function ()
```

You can implement that middleware like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Active
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user()->active){
            return redirect('login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to register this middleware into app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

 ....
  'active' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Active::class,

]
```

I hope this help

Comment: This answer would work, assuming there is a middleware called `active`, which checks the `users.active` column for the authenticated `User`. Is that available by default in Laravel 9, or do they need to manually add and configure that middleware?

Comment: There is no such middleware in Laravel 9 @Tim Lewis, they will have to make this manually, but that is really simple.

Comment: Yes it has to be added but it is simple enough to do. I have an active field in my users as workers come and go so

`  if (auth()->user()->active == 1) {
          return $next($request);`

Comment: Perfect! I knew that this Middleware did not exist, that was a prompt for you to show the code for that, so others do not think that is a default available middleware  Thank you for adding that code; this makes the answer that much better. Cheers!